# Use an array to change data without hardcoding into a sheet title

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba macro (2010) that when a button is clicked, the new year is filled out and the years on the tab names and all of the years in the data are updated to match the new year. Since I'm new, I have hardcoded all of this to the specific titles of each sheet. This means the button only works once before giving a subscript out of range error because the sheet has had a title change.

Is there a way I can use an array or something else to avoid hard coding to the title but still changing the year in the title so this code can be reused in the future?

I have:

```
For Each xlwksht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets( _
Array("FY15 GM Forecast (AMSG) Total", "FY15 GM Forecast (US)", _
"FY15 GM Forecast (MCU)", "FY15 GM Forecast (PDSN)"))
    xlwksht.Activate

    ::do something here::

Next xlwksht
```

When I run this to see if I am on the right track, I get a run-time error **'91'- object variable or With block not set**. I am uncertain how to set the variable and if I need a count. What I have tried hasn't worked yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Worksheets(index)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464(v=office.15).aspx) Property

```
Sub Test()    
Dim xlwksht As Worksheet
 For Each xlwksht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Array(1, 2, 3))
  xlwksht.Activate
  MsgBox ("Index:" & xlwksht.Index & vbCrLf & "Name: " & xlwksht.Name)
 Next xlwksht
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CodeName` which will not change -- [it is a read-only property of the worksheet class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552(v=office.15).aspx) -- unlike the index position which can change if you re-organize the sheets, remove some, etc.)

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Array(Sheet1.Name, Sheet2.Name))
    Debug.Print ws.Name
    ws.Activate
    'etc.
Next
```

This will of course raise an error if one or more of the sheets has been *deleted* from the workbook, but it will work no matter what you do to their Names or their relative positions within the workbook.

Comment: Thank you both. I'll try both to see which one decides it wants to work. I tried using the Sheet1, etc in another way but got a 91 error

Comment: I tried both. Both gave me an error 424 code- object required. Thinkingcap, your code had the messgae box pop up (not needed as the code changes the year) asking is that was the title but didn't change anything. After that I get the error code.

Comment: The code names like `sheet1` might need to be modified to reflect the sheets in your workbook.